# Using Model.destroy

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js

After going through the backbone documentation, it is evident that to send a delete request for a model we need to set the `urlRoot` and `id`. Another technique which came to my mind was to implement a `sync` for my model.

since my server uses `POST` for delete, i use `emulateHTTP = true`.
How can i acheive the above task so that the request url for my model will be of the form
`http://myWerService.com/myresource/deleteMyModel?modelName="abc"`

- So, how can i set my `id` as `modelName`
- What is the difference between the below two url patterns
  `http://myWerService.com/myresource/deleteMyModel?modelName="abc"`
  `http://myWerService.com/myresource/deleteMyModel/abc`

  The reason being, i saw every example use the second url pattern and i have no idea about the distinction between the two.
- I have the `url` set for this model for create request, how can i use a different url (i want to use the above specified url) for sending a delete request

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you are asking, but maybe this example will help:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    ID: 0,
    Name: '',

    ... other attributes for the model ...

},

initialize: function (id) {
    this.ID = id;
},

idAttribute: 'Name', // set the id attribute as the name attribute


// you can have different urls for different operations

methodToURL: {
    'read': 'GetModel',
    'update': 'UpdateModel',
    'delete': 'DeleteModel'

},

// overwrite the sync function

sync: function (method, model, options) {
    options = options || {};
    options.url = model.methodToURL[method.toLowerCase()];

    switch (method) {
        case 'read':
        case 'update':
        case 'delete':
            options.url += '/' + this.id;
            break;
    }

    Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
}
});
```

Comment: I implemented a similar functionality to use different urls as per the  request type and its working fine. But, i still cant figure out how to go for the delete request and setting the id, with "myModelName" attribute and the ".....?myModelName=abc" url.
Also, how can i view my requested url in console(The request url which is sent to the server).

Comment: Just treat any case like you want. For example, in that switch, you can say `case 'delete': options.url +='?myModelName='+this.id; break;` and leave the other cases with a `/id` route.

Comment: tried with the url as per your advice and generate the url pattern, but i am not able to pass this.id or this.vehicleNo value. The console say, Object HTMLInputElement.
I dont know why it is treating it as an htmlInputElement instead of a model attribute.

Comment: Can you please post the code for your model? this.id is an internal Backbone.Model attribute that should point to whatever attribute on the model you have set via `idAttribute: 'Name'`, in your case it should be the name. You can also try instead of `this.id` to use `this.get("Name")`.